# Azure - Configure disaster recovery and automatic failover for Azure API management?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, disaster-recovery

We have our Azure API management is provisioned in East US and our hot-standby region is West US.

I know that we can take the backup of the source APIM and restore it on destination APIM. However I want to have a hot-standby running parallel without serving until a DR situation.

How do I configure the Azure API management to support the disaster recovery with automatic fail over?
Would it impact the configured URLs/domains?

Comment: have you checked this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-deploy-multi-region

Comment: Thank you, it solves the issue. Can you please add the same as an answer?